# How To Install Google Play Services Through ADB cmd line Step by Step

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, adb

Good day, I was in the middle of running my application and I have `Google Map` included with it. I attempt to install `Google Play Store` but I failed, on Google's provided emulator, so instal `Genymotion`. And I do this things based on `Youtube` [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jbu8WT-naW4).

**Is this the right procedure of installing?**

Setp 1 : Download the following apk files.

1)com.google.android.gms.apk (https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934534438) 2)com.android.vending-4.4.22.apk (https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=23203820527945795)

Step 2 : Create a new AVD `Genymotion`

Step 3 : Run the AVD (Start the emulator) and Drag & Drop the downloaded files.

===> **I finished these steps still no `Play Store` appear.**  So I do the `CMD` approach.

Step 1 : Install the downloaded apks using `adb` through `CMD`.

```
 1)adb install com.google.android.gms-6.7.76_\(1745988-038\)-6776038-minAPI9.apk
 2)adb install com.android.vending-4.4.22.apk
```

Still `Google Play Store` don't appear.

Answer (score 3):

Any package can be installed through adb: when trying to replace and downgrade downgrade an existing package, you have to specify the -r and -d switches in an up to date adb.  I installed KatKiss-6.0_029.zip yesterday on my Transformer TF101, adn since the open_gapps-arm specified is nowhere to be found anymore, but I could find an old Google Play Services (10.0.84) somewhere on the web (package called base.apk), I installed it last, before the first login on my Pad, like this:

```
adb install -r -d -l base.apk
```

The -l (lock) is to lock google play services from future upgrades, since after this version it stopped working for me.  From that point on I could finally swipe in and set up my pad like before.

Comment: Is there a way to undo `-l` locking? I need to downgrade Google Play Services because it breaks many other Google apps on my Huawei phone, but I want to still be able to use newer version when Google ships a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to create AVD I assume you want to make your app work on emulator? If so, you should use just create your emulator instance using Google APIs, as described here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I forgot I already compiled the gms services and tried to run my application in genymotion with google play services installed, but I want to use the android studio emulator. I also downloaded the Google's API image.